# Как в React правильно организовать взаимодействие компонентов Link и Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Осваиваю React JS. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при переходе по ссылке, которая создана компонентом Link не происходит рендер соответствующего компонента указанного в роутере. Т.е. URL в браузере меняется, а содержимое страницы остается прежним.

**Файл routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './home';
import About from './about';

export default () => (
    <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/about' component={About} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
);
```

**Файл footer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';

import { grids } from 'pure-css';

let styles = {};
Object.assign( styles, grids );

class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wide-panel-decoration">
                <footer>
                    <div className='pure-g'>
                        <div className="pure-u-1-3">
                            &copy; Lab, 2018
                        </div>
                        <div className="pure-u-1-3">
                            asdsd
                        </div>
                        <div className="pure-u-1-3">
                            <BrowserRouter>
                                <nav>
                                    <Link to="/about">О проекте</Link>
                                </nav>
                            </BrowserRouter>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CSSModules( Footer, styles );
```

Comment: Такое чаще всего бывает когда ошибка в компоненте, в вашем случае в About, посмотрите консоль

Comment: Дмитрий, консоль чистая. Ошибок нет. Более того. Если просто зайти на страницу /about, то компоненты отрендарятся правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение проблемы!**

Link и Switch/Route находились в разных BrowserRouter, поэтому Link не находил подходящие роуты, так как их просто нету. Немного изменил структуру компонентов и все заработало.

**Измененный файл routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';

import Home from './home';
import About from './about';

export default () => (
    <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
);
```